# Does Elastic Search lock queries during Bulk Indexing?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm bulk inserting hundreds of documents into elastic search from a worker.
At the same time a user is running queries from a UI.

The problem is the queries either timeout, or are very slow, if the bulk indexing is going on at the same time as the query.

- Is that normal behaviour for Elastic search?
- Is there a way to run a query at the same time as the indexing or does Elastic lock the whole index?

It's fine if the query doesnt run over the latest documents.

I'm running the latest version of elasticsearch-py and Elastic, on Windows.

Comment: Elasticsearch is not locking the indexes while indexing. Most likely, your cluster cannot sustain the load you are putting on it (indexing, searching, maybe other processes running in parallel with Elasticsearch) and it's not doing well because of that.